# Is there a way to precache an Alembic sequence on RAM for faster playback?

Tags: animation, memory-management, alembic

I've been working with large Alembic files on a project recently, some in excess of 3 or 4 gigs of data and thousands of frames.

I notice that viewport playback takes severe hits with every ABC object I add into the scene. However, I'm still no where close to maxing out my available vram or memory.

I'm assuming that, since the ABC files live on an SSD, that they are read from the SSD at playback. I could be completely wrong about this, but I have DDR5 memory and a 12900ks in my system and I feel like if the ABCs were getting stored in RAM I shouldn't be noticing framerate drops to the magnitude I am.

Is it possible to make sure blender prefetches all the data in an ABC for smooth playback, or are the limitations I'm encountering due to some other aspect of the system?

Comment: I actually think that an SSD should be fast enough here. With a large amount of Alembic data, the real-time processing of this data is more likely to slow things down than reading the data.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you can tell blender to load the alembic files from memory but there is this cool addon:

https://github.com/neverhood311/Stop-motion-OBJ

It has the option to load the mesh into memory I dont know where you are exporting the alembic from but you need to convert the alembic into an obj sequence for it to work. You can use Houdini for that:

https://www.sidefx.com/forum/topic/39263/?page=1#post-180002

Hope this helps